# How to horizonally align this table?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

Is there a way to have a set (dynamic) spacing between the elements in this table without messing up horizontal alignment of the elements in the cell ?

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand*{\tabsep}{3ex}
\newcommand*{\TS}{\noalign{\vskip\tabsep}\pagebreak[1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[h]{l >{\RaggedRight}m{5cm} >{\RaggedRight}m{5cm} c c} 
\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}} code & Syntax & Gebruik & Is vector & Link
\\*\TS
\hline
\TS
\endhead
\texttt{pchisq()} & \begin{tabular}{l}\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{pchisq(}\textcolor{cyan}{<getal>},} \\*\TS \texttt{\textcolor{green}{df=<waarde>}\textcolor{blue}{)}} \\*\TS \texttt{\textcolor{green}{col=<getal>},} \\*\TS \texttt{\textcolor{red}{lwd=<getal>}} \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight}m{5cm}}Calculate P-value in a chi square test \\*\TS  degrees of freedom \\*\TS This code doesn't make sense, but neither does the vertical table alignment \\*\TS Random line width option \end{tabular} & $\surd$ & {$\leftarrow$} \\ 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative way to do it would be to use seperate table lines:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand*{\tabsep}{3ex}
\newcommand*{\TS}{\noalign{\vskip\tabsep}\pagebreak[1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[h]{l >{\RaggedRight}m{5cm} >{\RaggedRight}m{5cm} c c} 
\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}} code & Syntax & Gebruik & Is vector & Link
\\*\TS
\hline
\TS
\endhead
& \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{pchisq(}\textcolor{cyan}{<getal>},} & Calculate P-value in a chi square test \\
\\*\TS
& \texttt{\textcolor{green}{df=<waarde>}\textcolor{blue}{)}} & degrees of freedom \\
\texttt{pchisq()} & & & $\surd$ & $\leftarrow$ \\
& \texttt{\textcolor{green}{col=<getal>},} &  This code doesn't make sense, but neither does the vertical table alignment \\
\\*\TS
& \texttt{\textcolor{red}{lwd=<getal>}} & Random line width option \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

...but the result is still sloppy:

[image]

Does anybody know a cleaner solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps this? Using [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), `\multirow` and increasing a little `\arraystretch`:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand*{\tabsep}{3ex}
\newcommand*{\TS}{\noalign{\vskip\tabsep}\pagebreak[1]}

\begin{document}

{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{longtable}{l >{\RaggedRight}m{5cm} >{\RaggedRight}m{5cm} c c} 
\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}} code & Syntax & Gebruik & Is vector & Link \\
\toprule
\endhead
\multirow{6}{*}{\texttt{pchisq()}} 
  & \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{pchisq(}\textcolor{cyan}{<getal>},} 
  & Calculate P-value in a chi square test 
  & \multirow{6}{*}{$\surd$} 
  & \multirow{6}{*}{$\leftarrow$} 
\\
& \texttt{\textcolor{green}{df=<waarde>}\textcolor{blue}{)}} 
  & degrees of freedom 
\\
& \texttt{\textcolor{green}{col=<getal>},} 
  & This code doesn't make sense, but neither does the vertical table alignment 
\\
& \texttt{\textcolor{red}{lwd=<getal>}} 
  & Random line width option 
\\
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How robust is this arraystretch solution? Could I make it a variable one on a cell-by-cell basis, or would I have to declare seperate `longtable`s for that?

Comment: @1010011010 You can add space at any line break by using `\\[1cm]` or other appropriate distance.

Comment: @1010011010 `\arraystretch` is a LaTeX kernel command which affects the line spacing for every row on a `tabular` (the default value is `1`); the extra pair of braces in my code keep its redefinition local to the particular `longtable`. To change spacing between some particular rows, follow **cslstr**'s advise and use `\\[<length>]`.

Comment: @1010011010 or use `\addlinespace[<length>]` after ` \\ ` if you are using `booktabs`.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive/in-depth explanation. I'll have a look at that local solution as well because some cells have 4 rows while others have 7, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, using the `multirow`, `makecell` and  `booktabs` packages:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\newcommand*{\tabsep}{3ex}
%\newcommand*{\TS}{\noalign{\vskip\tabsep}\pagebreak[1]}
\renewcommand\cellalign{{m{5cm}}c}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[0.6 ex]}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[!h]{l *{2}{>{\RaggedRight}m{5cm}}*{2}{c}}%
\thead{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}} code} & \thead{Syntax} & \thead{Gebruik} & \thead{Is vector }& \thead{Link}
\\
\toprule
\addlinespace
%\TS
\endhead
\multirow{7}{*}{\texttt{pchisq()}}
&  \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{pchisq(}\textcolor{cyan}{<getal>},} & \makecell{Calculate P-value in a chi square test}
& \multirow{7}{*}{$\surd$} & \multirow{7}{*}{$\leftarrow$}\\%
&\texttt{\textcolor{green}{df=<waarde>}\textcolor{blue}{)}} & \makecell{ degrees of freedom} \\
& \texttt{\textcolor{green}{col=<getal>},} &  \makecell*{This code doesn't make sense, but neither does the vertical table alignment} &  \ \\
&  \texttt{\textcolor{red}{lwd=<getal>}} & \makecell*{Random line width option} \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a real answer to your question,
in that it does not display the content as a table within a table.
Nevertheless it may be useful
to consider alternative ways to present the content.

Instead of using a table within a table,
you could typeset the content as code with comments, e.g.

```
\begin{verbatim}
pchisq(<getal>, % calculate p-value in a chi square test
df =<waarde>,   % degrees of freedom
col=<getal>,    % This code doesn't make sense,
                % but neither does the vertical table alignment
lwd =<getal>)   % Random line width option
\end{verbatim}
```

If you were to use the `listings` package to display code,
then you could make the output more pretty (e.g. syntax highlighting).

Personally, I think the table within a table approach consumes a lot of paper,
and is hard to read.
In fact, the built-in documentation for `R` functions does not put a table within a table, but looks like the following:

> ### Description
>
> Density, distribution function, quantile function and random generation for the chi-squared (chi^2) distribution with df degrees of freedom and optional non-centrality parameter ncp.
>
> ### Usage
>
> ```
> dchisq(x, df, ncp = 0, log = FALSE)
> ...
> ```
>
> ### Arguments
>
> ```
> x, q     vector of quantiles.
> p        vector of probabilities.
> ...
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes I included this presentation as well in the full document. I like to present a variety of options so students can learn in their own way and indeed, listings is one of them, but a table-format is another. A small additional edit is that I don't intend to use the end product PDF as a physical paper, but rather an interactive PDF document including links and pop-up hints (probably JS based).